# Session value updated without intention

Tags: php, session

This problem is very weird to me. I am using jQuery to submit some ajax call, for example:

```
if($_POST['action']=="removeUser"){
$email=$_POST['id'];
$gname=$_POST['gname'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

include_once("inc/group.class.php");
$group=new group();

$array=array();
if($group->removeUser($gname,$email)){
    $array['stat']="success";
    $array['name']=$name;
}else{
    $array['stat']="fail";
}
echo json_encode($array);
exit;
}
```

This code is working fine.

But the weird thing is the `$email=$_POST['id'];` in the first line above which also updated session value `$_SESSION['email']` automatically after successfully executed.

For example, if $_POST['id']="abc@st.com", $_SESSION['email']="abc@st.com" automatically. I dont know how this could happen, though they share same name, but one is `$email`, another is `$_SESSION['email']`.

Anyone have idea why this could happen?

Thanks.

group.class

```
    public function removeUser($gname,$email){
    global $db;

    $query="DELETE FROM ec_join WHERE gname='$gname' AND member='$email'";

    $sql=$db->query($query) or die($db->error());

    if($sql){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: lol yeah and what does your group class look like?

Comment: Put `print_r($_SESSION); exit;` after `$email=$_POST['id']` and see if the $_SESSION value is different.  Otherwise, I suspect some code that isn't listed.

Comment: sorry, i have edited question several times now. basically, after submit $email='abc@st.com' to server, my session variable $_SESSION['email'] changed to 'abc@st.com' too.

Comment: hi, toast, yes, i tried print_r($_SESSION), the $_SESSION['email'] is changed immediately

Comment: Check out the only answer so far; I think that's your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable `register_globals` in PHP.ini as fast as you can.

Comment: I learned something, and I think that's exactly his problem.  +1 internet to you, sir.

Comment: hi, i tried ini_Get(register_globals) the result is '1' , what shall i do then

Comment: @bluedream, in `.htaccess` (Apache) put `php_flag register_globals off`, or in php.ini put `register_globals=0`.

Comment: i have tried, thanks so much, haha, yes, it is register_globals problem